# Join 3 tables using foreign keys, with two separate fields returned from the same table

Tags: mysql, join, key

I have three tables that look like this:

```
People:
+------------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| Field      | Type        | Null | Key | Default           | Extra          |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| id         | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment |
| fname      | varchar(32) | NO   |     | NULL              |                |
| lname      | varchar(32) | NO   |     | NULL              |                |
| dob        | date        | NO   |     | 0000-00-00        |                |
| license_no | varchar(24) | NO   |     | NULL              |                |
| date_added | timestamp   | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |                |
| status     | varchar(8)  | NO   |     | Allow             |                |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+

Units:
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id       | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| number   | varchar(3)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| resident | int(11)     | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| type     | varchar(16) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

Visits:
+----------+-----------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| Field    | Type      | Null | Key | Default             | Extra          |
+----------+-----------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| id       | int(11)   | NO   | PRI | NULL                | auto_increment |
| vis_id   | int(11)   | NO   | MUL | NULL                |                |
| unit     | int(11)   | NO   | MUL | NULL                |                |
| time_in  | timestamp | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP   |                |
| time_out | timestamp | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                |
+----------+-----------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
```

There are multiple foreign keys linking these tables:

```
units.resident -> people.id

visits.unit    -> units.id

visits.vis_id  -> people.id
```

Basically, I've tried to simplify my design and keep "residents" and "visitors" together in a table, but now I'm having trouble "linking" them together with a query... Here's what I'd like to be able to return from a query:

```
concat(p.lname, ', ', p.fname)
u.number
concat(p.lname, ', ', p.fname)
time_in
time_out
```

The first set of names should be from the resident, who we know is a resident because they're referenced by the foreign key in `units`. The `u.number` would return that resident's unit number, and the second set of names would be their current visitor (who *hasn't* checked out yet, determined by the `0000-00-00` timestamp... if they checked out, it wouldn't be `0000-00-00` and thus would not be displayed).

I'm starting to think that this either is too difficult for a novice like myself to figure out on my own, or that my DB design is flawed... The reason I wanted all residents and visitors in the same table is that I'd like them *all* to be searchable using a `fulltext` index.

If you have suggestions, I'm all ears as I've been beating my head against a wall for days over this one...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about something like

```
SELECT  concat(p.lname, ', ', p.fname)
        u.number
        concat(pv.lname, ', ', pv.fname)
        v.time_in
        v.time_out
FROm    units u LEFT JOIN
        people p    ON  u.resident = p.id LEFT JOIN
        visits v    ON  u.id = v.unit LEFT JOIN
        people pv   ON  v.vis_id = pv.id
```

For a basic introduction to joins have a look at[Introduction to JOINs – Basic of JOINs](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/04/13/sql-server-introduction-to-joins-basic-of-joins/)

Comment: Also, if you don't mind, could you tell me a little about why I'd use left joins? I'm pretty new, so I don't really understand why I need to use them as opposed to inner joins...

Comment: I'll check that out, thanks for your help. I'd give you a vote but I don't have enough rep!